# is pipeline.fit a Transformation or Action

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, pipeline

Is pipeline.fit method a Tranformation or Action

unable to query documentation which points to this

when will the computation start , in pipeline.fit or model.tranform or collect()

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
from pyspark.ml.feature import HashingTF, Tokenizer

# Prepare training documents from a list of (id, text, label) tuples.
training = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, "a b c d e spark", 1.0),
    (1, "b d", 0.0),
    (2, "spark f g h", 1.0),
    (3, "hadoop mapreduce", 0.0)
], ["id", "text", "label"])

# Configure an ML pipeline, which consists of three stages: tokenizer, hashingTF, and lr.
tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="text", outputCol="words")
hashingTF = HashingTF(inputCol=tokenizer.getOutputCol(), outputCol="features")
lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=10, regParam=0.001)
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[tokenizer, hashingTF, lr])

# Fit the pipeline to training documents.
model = pipeline.fit(training)

# Prepare test documents, which are unlabeled (id, text) tuples.
test = spark.createDataFrame([
    (4, "spark i j k"),
    (5, "l m n"),
    (6, "spark hadoop spark"),
    (7, "apache hadoop")
], ["id", "text"])

# Make predictions on test documents and print columns of interest.
prediction = model.transform(test)
selected = prediction.select("id", "text", "probability", "prediction")
for row in selected.collect():
    rid, text, prob, prediction = row
    print("(%d, %s) --> prob=%s, prediction=%f" % (rid, text, str(prob), prediction))
```

Comment: Do you agree with the answer?

Comment: Yes i do Thanks again @thebluephantom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transformation. If you look in the Spark UI and you run with no Action as such, you will observe no Jobs, Tasks, Stages, etc.

Comment: But sometimes you can get data error when you run fit?

Comment: this is not my question. It belongs to different user.

Comment: Indeed, sorry. But yes errors can result. In any even it is correct. !!!

Comment: how did you learn no job task running while no action. i read the book but didnt know it. upvoted

Comment: They are also sequential. Lazy evaluation. This is one of may good blogs. https://data-flair.training/blogs/apache-spark-lazy-evaluation/

Comment: Yes Indeed it is a transformation, once commented, it no longer executes jobs, thanks @thebluephantom, accepted the answer, apologize for the delay :D